# How to fix Kubernetes Ingress Controller cutting off nodes from cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, kong

I'm having some trouble installing an Ingress Controller in my on-prem cluster (created with Kubespray, running MetalLB to create LoadBalancer.).

I tried using nginx, traefik and kong but all got the same results.

I'm installing my the nginx helm chart using the following values.yaml:

```
controller:
  kind: DaemonSet
  nodeSelector:
    node-role.kubernetes.io/master: ""
  image:
    tag: 0.23.0
rbac:
  create: true
```

With command:

```sh
helm install --name nginx stable/nginx-ingress --values values.yaml --namespace ingress-nginx
```

When I deploy the ingress controller in the cluster, a service is created (e.g. nginx-ingress-controller for nginx). This service is of the type LoadBalancer and gets an external IP.

When this external IP is assigned, the node that's linked to this external IP is lost (status Not Ready). However, when I check this node, it's still running, it's just cut off from the other
nodes, it can't even ping them (No route found). When I remove the service (not the rest of the nginx helm chart), everything works and the Ingress works. I also tried installing nginx/traefik/kong without a LoadBalancer using NodePorts or External IPs on the service, but I get the same result.

Does anyone recognize this behaviour?
Why does the ingress still work, even when I remove the nginx-ingress-controller service?

Comment: Can you please elaborate this - "node that's linked to this external IP is lost "  Do you mean, that node and ingress service attempting to assign the same public IP?

Comment: Hi @A_Suh, thanks for your response! The external IP for the service is the IP of one of the 5 nodes in my cluster. Let's call that node X. When the service is created and gets an external IP, X gets status "Not Ready". However, X is not down, since I can still log in to it and kubelet is still running. The moment the service is installed in my cluster, X can't access the master node anymore so its health pings can't reach master anymore. When I ping to the master node (or any other node) from X, I get "Destination Host Unreachable".

Comment: this is weird your DHCP server  is assigning IP to the service, which has been already assigned to the node.  Would you try to manually set a static IP address to your ingress service? i.e. `apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 10.10.10.10`

Comment: Aha, so it seems I have misconfigured something. Since the load balancer is running inside the cluster, shouldn't the load balancer IP be the IP of one of the nodes inside the cluster? I configured MetalLB to provide a range of IP addresses to the load balancers and these IP's are the IP's of the nodes in my cluster. I'm sorry, I'm new to Kubernetes and I think I'm missing something?

Comment: No it shouldn't be the same. You are exposing access to the service as a separate object. So, please amend the range of the IPs for the LB not to intersect with node's IPs

Comment: I tried using an IP address outside of my cluster, but when I check the services, the external IP of my ingress controller remains pending? Also, when I take a look at the documentation of MetalLB, I read "In the simplest possible scenario, the pool is composed of the IP addresses of Kubernetes nodes, but IP addresses can also be handed out by a DHCP server." (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/) Since I don't use the DHCP server to hand out IP addresses, it seems to me that I have to provide IP addresses of the nodes in my cluster? Or am I missing something?

Comment: oh, you were right, for MetalLB you have to provide IP addresses of the nodes. Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: Hi @A_Suh, I just managed to solve this issue. It turns out you were right and I did need to specify IPs outside of the cluster to fix this. The reason why this didn't work at first, was because DHCP wasn't configured in my network. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a long search, we finally found a working solution for this problem.

As mentioned by @A_Suh, the pool of IPs that metallb uses, should contain IPs that are currently not used by one of the nodes in the cluster. By adding a new IP range that's also configured in the DHCP server, metallb can use ARP to link one of the IPs to one of the nodes.

For example in my 5 node cluster (kube11-15): When metallb gets the range 10.4.5.200/31 and allocates 10.4.5.200 for my nginx-ingress-controller,  10.4.5.200 is linked to kube12. On ARP requests for 10.4.5.200, all 5 nodes respond with kube12 and trafic will be routed to this node.